# How to replace a word with another, but considering the spaces?

Tags: c#, replace

I have this function:

```
public static string Autocorrect(string input) 
{
    string output = "";
    output = input.Replace("ad", "and");
    return output;
}
```

It replace all the "ad" occurrences with and, but also to word ads -> ands, the expectation in this example is that ads should remain the same.
I want to replace only the word ad, not if a word contains "ad". How can I do this?

Comment: Yeap you should consider spaces. So instead you should replace ` ad ` with ` and `

Comment: Regex replace and word boundaries come to mind :)

Comment: `string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\bad\b", "and");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `\b` matches a backspace. Did you mean `\s` (white space). But even then you would miss the first and last word in a sentence (not likely for "and", but it might be just an example).

Comment: @bags Split the string into words (see string.Split) and replace them on full equality. But you would still have to deal with casing and punctuation.

Comment: @Jürgen Röhr: `\b` stands for *word boundary* which can be white space, punctuation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static string Autocorrect(string input) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)
  ? input
  : Regex.Replace(input, @"\bad\b", "and");
```

**Pattern** `@"\bad\b"` **explained:**

```
  \b - word boundary (white space, punctuation, beginning of the string etc.)
  ab - just "ab"
  \b - word boundary (white space, punctuation, end of the string etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

add spcace before and after ***ad***

```
output = input.Replace(" ad ", "and");
//or
//output =Regex.Replace(input, @"\bad\b", "and")
```

If you want to be space before and after ***and***

```
output = input.Replace(" ad ", " and ");
//or
//output =Regex.Replace(input, @"\bad\b", " and ")
```

Comment: `input.Replace(" ad ", " and ")` doesn't pay attention to *punctuation*, beginning and end of the string. Nothing will be changed in `"ad - start, with punctuation: ad, at the end: ad"`

Comment: Better `Regex.Replace(input, @"\bad\b", "and")` (note `"and"` instead of `" and "`); we should not add extra spaces

Comment: Apparently, the questioner wants to replace ad with and in a text...